# Reference relative path inside JS config file in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to incorporate [this scanning](https://developer.dynamsoft.com/dwt/guide/building-the-hello-world-scan-page) software into an application.

The folder which contains all the necessary `.js`, `.css` and binary files is called `Resources`.

In my MVC app - I have placed the `Resources` file inside my `Scripts` folder.

In my `.cshtml`, I have the following:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.config.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.initiate.js"></script>
}
```

Which loads the scripts successfully.

The issue I'm facing is the scripts themselves reference relative paths within the `Resources` folder.

In `dynamsoft.webtwain.config.js` - you can set the path to the resources folder - I have mine set to the following:

`Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ResourcesPath = '~/Scripts/Resources';`

However when the page loads - I'm receiving 404 errors for some of the files because it's trying to literally interpret the path:

[image: 404 for resource files]

I have also tried the following but with no luck:

```
Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ResourcesPath = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Resources")';
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use relative paths starting with tilde (`~`) in separate JS files because `@Url.Content()` helper and ASP.NET relative paths only work inside Razor view page, but you can pass the relative path by creating root path in JS **global scope** (i.e. Razor view page's `<script>` tag) like this:

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
</script>
```

Then you can include the path inside JS files using that variable:

```
// custom JS file
if (typeof baseUrl !== 'undefined') {
    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ResourcesPath = baseUrl + '/Scripts/Resources';
}
```

Or simply mentioning full path & pass it:

```
@* Razor page *@
<script>
    var resourcesPath = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Resources")';
</script>

// custom JS file
if (typeof resourcesPath !== 'undefined') {
    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ResourcesPath = resourcesPath;
}
```

Another alternative is using custom JS view engine together with file handler for JS scripts like example below:

```
// custom JS engine
public class CustomJSEngine : BuildManagerViewEngine
{
    public CustomJSEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/Scripts/{0}.js",
            "~/Scripts/Resources/{0}.js"
        };

        FileExtensions = new[]
        {
            "js"
        };
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        var view = new RazorView(controllerContext, viewPath,
                                 layoutPath: masterPath, runViewStartPages: true, viewStartFileExtensions: FileExtensions,
                                 viewPageActivator: ViewPageActivator);
        return view;
    }
}

// put these lines below inside Application_Start()
RazorCodeLanguage.Languages.Add("js", new CSharpRazorCodeLanguage());
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomJSEngine());

// add this line if necessary
WebPageHttpHandler.RegisterExtension(".js");
```

References:

[@Url.Content in separate javascript file using ASPNET MVC 3 and Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663486/url-content-in-separate-javascript-file-using-aspnet-mvc-3-and-razor)

[Returning razor-parsed Javascript as a ViewResult from a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220403/returning-razor-parsed-javascript-as-a-viewresult-from-a-controller)

Comment: Mentioning the full path as `var resourcesPath = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Resources")';` worked - thanks!